# Multiple Async postbacks at the same time - ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, webforms

Say I have 2 `UpdatePanels` on the page and each `UpdatePanel` has a one server `Button` each. When I click on the first button and then the second button and look in Firebug, I see that the 2nd async postback is not triggered until the first one completes.

Is this working as expected? My understanding was with AJAX postbacks, the event handlers for the buttons trigger simultaneously.

**EDIT: Any help anyone?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is accurate for that model. You probably want pagemethods.

**EDIT:** drachenstern says "finally back at my computer"

Here's the thing: An UpdatePanel is fundamentally a page-postback. It can only post one event at a time. The model doesn't understand two simultaneous events. So each click is one full postback. Therefore it doesn't start the one till the other finishes.

So like I said, it's accurate behavior for the model. There's not really much you can do to alter the model except to define your own model. You can't just want the model to do something that you want without being able to define what you want to happen.

Comment: My button event handlers need to access other controls. PageMethods need to be static

Comment: @DaveS ~ I updated my answer. You're not going to like my answer tho I imagine. My advice is to figure out how to make your events static/stateless, otherwise I don't think this will work like you want it to.

Comment: Multiple partial postbacks *can* be triggered at the same time - this will result on them 'stepping on each other', but it *can* and *does* happen. Extra work (ie. that which is done by SharePoint) is required to add a block to this 'stepping on' behavior.

Comment: Well yes, I was trying to follow the naive case as that's where most developers are when they ask these sorts of questions. I can think of ways to force multiple concurrent and simultaneous events to occur. Please don't be pedantic and downvote out of "hurr hurr you're slightly wrong"