# Async postbacks to the same target are cancelled

Tags: javascript, asp.net, pagerequestmanager

I'm using manually initiated postbacks to do some magic in a demonstration I'm making.

This is the function I'm using to initiate them:

```
function doPostBackAsync(eventName, eventArgs) {
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    prm.beginAsyncPostBack(null, eventName, eventArgs, false);
}
```

The problem I am having is that if the request is not completed before the user triggers a new postback, the request is cancelled.

The only solution I've thought of is to add a random value to the query string, but in order to do so I would have to abandon using this function and likely create an ajax request, thus requiring significant rework to achieve the functionality I've developed thus far.

Any ideas?

Comment: Thinking that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415208/multiple-async-postbacks-at-the-same-time-asp-net is relevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415208/multiple-async-postbacks-at-the-same-time-asp-net) it is my impression that this is a limitation of the framework I'm trying to leverage.